# UITableView in UIViewController Root View Showing

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a Table View inside of a View Controller. I need to have a section above the table view which is why I am not using a Table View Controller. When I attempt this, the app runs and the data in the table populates; however, the label and button in the section above the table view does not display.

I am adding this view as a subview to the root view controller, and the content above the table view in the view is actually the background of the root view controller.

I have attached a generic screenshot below. Any thoughts?

[image: Sample storyboard screenshot]

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: please attach screenshot after running on the simulator to get clear idea

Answer (score 0):

First, try this command with IBoutlet in ViewDidLoad()

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(yourView)
```

Comment: I tried this using the header view as the "yourView" in the code above. This did not solve the problem

Comment: And then we need to clarify the position of the label and button in storyboard structure and how they are shown on the simulator. Or the only way is that just imagine your code and situation.

Answer (score 0):

If your view controller is on navigation controller stack then you need to uncheck 2 options from your storyboard for your viewcontroller[image]

You need to deselect 1.Under Top Bars 2. Under bottom Bars

Comment: It is not on a navigation controller stack. I am programmatically pushing the view controller on top of the root view, which is used as a controller view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you are doing, why not try to make the custom view (the section above that you mentioned) as the header of your tableView.

Comment: I want the header to be static and not pull down from the top. I am using a refresh control that would pull the header down in a table view.